# StreamWriter file in use by another process - Writing to fast too frequently?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm getting an error with StreamWriter that the file is in use by another process, but I believe it may be down to the speed at which I'm writing the file or more specifically the speed of it being opened/closed.

The code is as follows:

```
    public static void writeLog(string msg)
    {
        StreamWriter log;
        string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
        string currentYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
        string directoryName = currentMonth + "-" + currentYear;

        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\AutoSkill\LogFiles\" + directoryName + @"\"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\AutoSkill\LogFiles\" + directoryName + @"\");
        }

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string date = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yy");

        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\AutoSkill\LogFiles\" + directoryName + @"\" + date + ".txt"))
        {
            log = new StreamWriter(@"C:\AutoSkill\LogFiles\" + directoryName + @"\" + date + ".txt");
        }
        else
        {
            log = File.AppendText(@"C:\AutoSkill\LogFiles\" + directoryName + @"\" + date + ".txt");
        }

        try
        {
            log.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error writing to the log file.");
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
        }
        log.Close();
    }
```

So I'm closing the log each time I'm done writing to it, but I'm writing all out my output from the console screen to the file to keep track of what actually happened; sometimes the lines are only a few milliseconds apart if the action that was taken was quick or just returned null.

Am i getting this error due to speed of writing to the file? Is there a better way to handle writing a log file?

Comment: _"Is there a better way to handle writing a log file"_ Yes, use an available logging framework like [log4net](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial)

Comment: Apart from what Tim says, `Close()` should definitely close the file. Unless a virus scanner interferes, or if multiple threads call this code at the same time.

Comment: You could always just `File.AppendAllText(path, msg + "\r\n")` and move on.  (Directory.Exists is not necessary btw)

Comment: Appending to a file is very slow.  Better to keep file open.  Also at end you may need to flush to get all the data into the file.  Just closing sometimes data is loss.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks ill look into this, but with this piece I have to use just vanilla methods as I cant install extras on a works PC

Comment: @BenR: why your company forbids to use professional tools which are free and state of the art?

Comment: @BenR You don't have to install log4net on your computer, it is downloaded specifically for this project by NuGet and included to project as extra DLL, same for any NuGet package.

Comment: @TimSchmelter security, unauthorised applications/additions. I could probable apply for it but I'm just an amateur coder and dont need something to that level, at least not at this stage. But i realised what the issue was, just my own blindness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard this, I'm dumb.

I've not had this problem for the last 2 years, I'm getting the error because I'm writing to the same file from a different thread, which is where the overlap is.

The file actually is in use by another process, the same one just a different thread.